# What will happen if I use one database connection instance in whole application in a concurrency system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, database-connection

I am working on asp.net MVC+WebAPI entity framework code-first project, and using async methods. Currently, I am creating database connection on per-call basis.

Creating database connection takes small time, 
so every request to server needs small time to create a database connnection,
and for thousand requests it takes more time.

Now, my question is if I use one database connection instance in whole application then what will be happened?

Comment: You should also consider a caching policy.  There may be data you don't need to retrieve from the database every time or have the mechanisms in place to refresh the cache when an item becomes stale.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server and Oracle have connection pools, so the actual resources behind the database connection are typically going to be reused even though you create a connection class for each call.

If you have a singleton connection you won't be able to have concurrent database requests. You'll have a single-thread bottleneck to the database.

The connection pool will grow and shrink depending on how much concurrency you application actually has.